# Indexing Non-Blank Values for a Unique Value in R

Tags: r

I have hundreds-of-thousands of rows, which most of them have missing values (column 2). Based on a primary key (column 1), I can assume that the missing values can be imputed with values associated with that key. An example would be necessary.

```
Primary Key Date       Date.Impute
123         ""  
123         ""  
123         02/02/2017  
1234        ""  
1234        02/03/2017  
1234        ""  
12345       01/01/2017  
12345       ""
```

All orders "123" date are "02/02/2017". All orders "1234" date are "02/03/2017", etc..

Using or not using index match-like feature in R, how can I fill in all of the missing fields of the 2nd column in the 3rd column? The end result should like the following:

```
Primary Key Date          Date.Impute
123         ""            02/02/2017
123         ""            02/02/2017
123         02/02/2017    02/02/2017    
1234        ""            02/03/2017
1234        02/03/2017    02/03/2017
1234        ""            02/03/2017
12345       01/01/2017    01/01/2017
12345       ""            01/01/2017
```

I know how to do this in Excel and would gladly share it, but would like to understand how to do this in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See `?as.Date` to convert your dates to to a valid R format first. @Rich It should be conditioned on `Primary Key`, not always on which row comes first, judging by their excerpt above. (They could prolly sort then do na.locf, though...)

Comment: All dates are in the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reproducible Data

I added an extra row with `Primary.Key == 123456` does not have a single `Date` value

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(Primary.Key = c(123,123,123,1234,1234,1234,12345,12345,123456),
         Date=mdy(NA,NA,"02/02/2017",NA,"02/03/2017",NA,"01/01/2017",NA,NA),
         Date.Impute=as.Date(rep(NA,9)), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

#### dplyr and purrr solution

Use `ifelse` to deal with entries like `Primary.Key == 123456` without a single `Date` value. I also changed from using `unique` to `tail(sort(),1)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
L <- split(df, df$Primary.Key)           # split by Primary.Key groups into list
df1 <- map_df(L, ~.x %>% mutate(Date.Impute = ifelse(length(tail(sort(Date),1))==0, as.character(NA), as.character(tail(sort(Date),1)))))
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(Date.Impute = ymd(Date.Impute))
```

#### Output

```
  Primary.Key       Date Date.Impute
1         123       <NA>  2017-02-02
2         123       <NA>  2017-02-02
3         123 2017-02-02  2017-02-02
4        1234       <NA>  2017-02-03
5        1234 2017-02-03  2017-02-03
6        1234       <NA>  2017-02-03
7       12345 2017-01-01  2017-01-01
8       12345       <NA>  2017-01-01
9      123456       <NA>        <NA>
```

Comment: Hi @Chi Pak. This works as described. Thank you for assisting. When applied to a larger dataframe, especially where "Primary.Key" has one row and the date is missing or is not missing, I receive the error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column Date.Impute must be length 2 (the number of rows) or one, not 0. I modified your logic to `df1 <- map_df(L, ~.x %>% mutate(Date.Impute = unique(Date[!is.na(Date)]) || ifelse(nrow(Date) <=2, Date$Impute = Date)))`. Thoughts?

Comment: It didn't necessarily fix it, but it did give me back a dataframe with Date.Impute with "TRUE" values w/ about half the dataset I originally started with.

Comment: Ok, I think it's skipped over groups where `Primary.Key` does not have a date value. If you specify what value you want to use for imputing, I could give it a shot.

Comment: @ Chi Pak, a zero or NA would be fine. Thoughts? Thanks, Starbucks

Answer (score 6):

in base R, you can simply do

```
merge(df, unique(df[df$Date!="",]), by="Primary.Key", all.x = T)

#  Primary.Key     Date.x     Date.y
#1         123            02/02/2017
#2         123            02/02/2017
#3         123 02/02/2017 02/02/2017
#4        1234            02/03/2017
#5        1234 02/03/2017 02/03/2017
#6        1234            02/03/2017
#7       12345 01/01/2017 01/01/2017
#8       12345            01/01/2017
```

Comment: `library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(Primary.Key = c(123,123,123,1234,1234,1234,12345,12345),
                 Date=mdy(NA,NA,"02/02/2017",NA,"02/03/2017",NA,"01/01/2017",NA),
                 Date.Impute=as.Date(rep(NA,8)), stringsAsFactors=F)

merge(df, unique(df[df$Date!="",]), by="Primary.Key", all.x = T)`

Throws an error "in as.POSIXIt,character(x,tx),  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"
However there is no POSIXIt information in the proxy dataframe. Is the error referring to the formating of missing data?

Comment: Giving your definition of the df you would do `merge(df, unique(df[as.character(df$Date)!="",])[1:2], by="Primary.Key", all.x = T)`. The variable `df$Date` needs to be character or factor in order to use it in `df$Date!=""`

Answer (score 1):

This might turn out a bit slow... but at least something to work with:

```
for (key in unique(df$Primary_Key)) {
  keyrows <- df$Primary_Key == key
  key_d <- df[keyrows & df$Date != "", "Date"][1]
  df[keyrows, "Date.impute"] <- key_d
}

df

  Primary_Key       Date Date.impute
1         123             02/02/2017
2         123             02/02/2017
3         123 02/02/2017  02/02/2017
4        1234             02/03/2017
5        1234 02/03/2017  02/03/2017
6        1234             02/03/2017
7       12345 01/01/2017  01/01/2017
8       12345             01/01/2017
```

It does deal with the case of there being two dates for one primary key by just selecting the first date that appears.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Primary_Key = c(rep(123L, 3), rep(1234L, 3), rep(12345L, 2)), 
                 Date = c("", "", "02/02/2017", "", "02/03/2017", "", 
                          "01/01/2017", ""), 
                 Date.impute = "",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```